# Audacity recording extremely slow in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, audacity

Audacity is suddenly recording extremely slowly (at what seems to be 0,1x speed), which means that at playback the sound is played at a very high pitch and much faster than the original. If I then artificially slow down the sound, a great deal of quality is lost...

To help you understand the issue, I've shot [a tiny video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe20eQNvZVA).

Look at the seconds hand of the xclock and how much it is moving before Audacity is done recording one second of audio (the scale at the top is in seconds)

Things I've already tried:

- Purging and reinstalling Audacity
- Purging and reinstalling Pulseaudio following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)
- Running audacity with this command: `Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 audacity`

Nothing of interest appears in dmesg or in the audacity log, except a bunch of `Expression 'stream->playback.pcm' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 4611`

The machine is a Ryzen 5 1600 with an ASUS X370 Prime motherboard.
The kernel is 4.13.0.38 amd64.

Edit: possibly the same thing that was asked in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998476/microphone-recording-approximately-12x-slower-than-normal-in-certain-application?rq=1) that has no answer.

Edit 2: found [another similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935077/pulseaudio-is-recording-in-slow-mo?rq=1) to mine, and the person has the same motherboard as me. I tried `exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 audacity` as he suggested but the problem is still there.

Edit 3: I've tried to replicate the problem in a live DVD session of Xubuntu 17.10.1 and the problem is still present. I am beginning to think this is a kernel or Pulseaudio bug regarding the motherboard I am using...

Edit 4: I've also tried with Xubuntu 18.04 daily live DVD and the problem is still there...
Strangely, the problem also occurs in an Xubuntu 17.10 VirtualBox virtual machine (The host is Ubuntu 16.04)... (All versions are 64-bit)

Edit 2018-06-17: There is [a bug report now on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1764965) about this. The problem is still present in Ubuntu 18.04 stable...

Many thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: The bug report shows a workaround. However it's buried in the replies so I answered this (very similar) [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998476/microphone-recording-approximately-12x-slower-than-normal-in-certain-application) so that affected people can quickly work around the issue until a fix has been released.